# Fast way to find length and start index of repeated elements in array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array A:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array( [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,0, 1, 0] )
```

The length of consecutive '1s' would be:

```
output: [3, 2, 1]
```

with the corresponding starting indices:

```
idx = [2, 6, 10]
```

The original arrays are huge and I prefer a solution with less for-loop.

Edit (Run time):

```
import numpy as np
import time

A = np.array( [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,0, 1, 0] )

def LoopVersion(A):
    l_A = len(A)
    size = []
    idx = []
    temp_idx = []
    temp_size = []
    for i in range(l_A):
        if A[i] == 1:
            temp_size.append(1)
            if not temp_idx:
                temp_idx = i
                idx.append(temp_idx)
        else:
            size.append( len(temp_size) )
            size = [i for i in size if i != 0]
            temp_size = []
            temp_idx = []
    return size, idx
```

**Quang's solution:**

```
def UniqueVersion(A):
    _, idx, counts = np.unique(np.cumsum(1-A)*A, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
    return idx, counts
```

**Jacco's solution:**

```
def ConcatVersion(A):
    A = np.concatenate(([0], A, [0]))  #  get rid of some edge cases
    starts = np.argwhere((A[:-1] + A[1:]) == 1).ravel()[::2]
    ends = np.argwhere((A[:-1] + A[1:]) == 1).ravel()[1::2]
    len_of_repeats = ends - starts
    return starts, len_of_repeats
```

**Dan's solution (works with special cases as well):**

```
def structure(A):
    ZA = np.concatenate(([0], A, [0]))
    indices = np.flatnonzero( ZA[1:] != ZA[:-1] )
    counts = indices[1:] - indices[:-1]
    return indices[::2], counts[::2]
```

Run time analysis with 10000 elements:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
B = np.random.randint(2, size=10000)


start = time.time()
size, idx = LoopVersion(B)
end = time.time()
print ( (end - start) )
# 0.32489800453186035 seconds

start = time.time()
idx, counts = UniqueVersion(B)
end = time.time()
print ( (end - start) )
# 0.008305072784423828 seconds

start = time.time()
idx, counts = ConcatVersion(B)
end = time.time()
print ( (end - start) )
# 0.0009801387786865234 seconds

start = time.time()
idx, counts = structure(B)
end = time.time()
print ( (end - start) )
# 0.000347137451171875 seconds
```

Comment: What have you tried so far that has failed and made you decide, as a last resort, to post on SO?

Comment: See edit. Code works but is not efficient.

Comment: Just throwing this out there. This may be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Not that this is a bad question, but it may not truly be the question you should be asking.

Comment: Since it's a case of efficiency, sketch out a diagram of an algorithm to solve the problem. Try to make that one more efficient then write it in python.

Comment: Your implementation of Jacco's solution is not ideal. There is no need to compute `np.argwhere` twice. Consider calling the function once and storing the result in a variable instead of making two calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pedestrian try, solving the problem by programming the problem.

We prepend and also append a zero to `A`, getting a vector `ZA`, then detect the `1` islands, and the `0` islands coming in alternating manner in the `ZA` by comparing the shifted versions `ZA[1:]` and `ZA[-1]`. (In the constructed arrays we take the even places, corresponding to the ones in `A`.)

```
import numpy as np

def structure(A):
    ZA = np.concatenate(([0], A, [0]))
    indices = np.flatnonzero( ZA[1:] != ZA[:-1] )
    counts = indices[1:] - indices[:-1]
    return indices[::2], counts[::2]
```

Some sample runs:

```
In [71]: structure(np.array( [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0] ))
Out[71]: (array([ 2,  6, 10]), array([3, 2, 1]))

In [72]: structure(np.array( [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1] ))
Out[72]: (array([ 0,  5,  9, 13, 15]), array([3, 3, 2, 1, 1]))

In [73]: structure(np.array( [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0] ))
Out[73]: (array([0, 5, 9]), array([3, 3, 2]))

In [74]: structure(np.array( [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1] ))
Out[74]: (array([ 0,  2,  5,  7, 11, 14]), array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's try `unique`:

```
_, idx, counts = np.unique(np.cumsum(1-A)*A, return_index=True, return_counts=True)

# your expected output:
idx, counts
```

Output:

```
(array([ 2,  6, 10]), array([3, 2, 1]))
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the first group contains ones because the inverted cumsum will be zero for this group and the following group of zeros. Failing example: [1,1,1,0,0,0].

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Good catch, thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer with boolean slicing instead of multiplication.

Comment: Actually at second thought, that only makes it worse returning misaligned index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that the indexes of '1s' provide all information you need. It's enough to find starts and ends of series of '1s'.

```
A = np.concatenate(([0], A, [0]))  #  get rid of some edge cases
diff = np.argwhere((A[:-1] + A[1:]) == 1).ravel()
starts = diff[::2]
ends = diff[1::2]
    
print(starts, ends - starts)
```

Comment: That's even faster. Thanks. I updated the original post with your solution. Could you please explain the first line?

Comment: An array ending with `0, 1` will produce `ends` array shorter than `starts`. On the other hand, an array starting with several `1s` won't be properly counted.  This is because I remove first and last element of `A` to create `diff` array (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

Consider also the more-itertools [`locate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.locate) and [`consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups) tools.

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


data = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]      # or numpy array
```

**Code**

```
indices = list(mit.locate(data))
```

```
group_lengths = [len(list(group)) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(indices)]

starting_indices = [list(group)[0] for group in mit.consecutive_groups(indices)]
```

Results

```
group_lengths
# [3, 2, 1]

starting_indices
# [2, 6, 10]
```

---

**Details**

- `locate` yields indices of every `1`
- `consecutive_groups` yields groups of runs, e.g. `(1, 2, 3), (8, 9)`
- the groups are iterators, from which you get the length and first index

[`more-itertools`](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools) is a third-party library.  `> pip install more-itertools`